# Как убрать название экшена из урл на yii2

Tags: yii2

vote2/kategorii/remont-noutbukov  
vote2/category/remont-noutbukov/zamena-razyema-pitaniya    
vote2/card/remont-noutbukov/zamena-razyema-pitaniya/sentr-2

kategorii,category, card  название экшенов. Как убрать эти экшены из урл чтобы было так:

vote2/remont-noutbukov   
vote2/remont-noutbukov/zamena-razyema-pitaniya   
vote2/remont-noutbukov/zamena-razyema-pitaniya/sentr-2

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.
Попробуйте так, в правилах urlManager()

```
'<remont-noutbukov>' => 'controller/kategorii/remont-noutbukov'
```

Answer (score 0):

изначально url выглядел так:

```
vote2/main/kategorii?al=remont-noutbukov
```

код в urlManager() 
`'kategorii/<al:[\w\-]+>'=>'main/kategorii',
'<action:kategorii>' => 'main/<action>',`

стало: `vote2/kategorii/remont-noutbukov`

что надо писать в правилах чтобы убрать "kategorii".

не помогло `'<remont-noutbukov>' => 'controller/kategorii/remont-noutbukov'`